# fetch database data with singleton design pattern

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns

I'm using singleton design pattern for connect to database.In below I run a query on my database and I want to fetch data from this query :

```
$db = Db::connect();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
while ($row = ???) {
// echo 'myTable' fields here. like = echo $row['someField']
}
```

my Db class:

```
class Db
{
    private $connection;
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $name = "dictionary";

        $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new Db();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
        $records = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        return $records;
    }
}
```

What should I write instead of `???` in my code ?

Comment: What do you want to do in the while loop? we dont know what $row is holding,

Comment: `$query->fetch()`?

Comment: `while($row = $query->fetch_array()){ ...` may be? Plus we don't know what inside `Db` class i.e implementation details of singleton pattern.

Comment: Without your `Db class` source code, we can't help you...

Comment: @RadjdeepPaul I update my question.please check it .

Comment: @TakaapoPage check my answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while ($row = ???) {
    // echo 'myTable' fields here. like = echo $row['someField']
}
```

with

```
foreach($query as $row)
    echo $row['someField'];
```

Note : You may want to rename `$query` to `$rows`, for example, since this is a more appropriate name.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of `while` loop, use `array_shift()` function to get the current row from the result set, like this:

```
while ($row = array_shift($query)) {
    echo $row['someField'] . "<br />";
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to your Database class's `->query()` method returns an array of result rows. So all you need to do is process that array like any other

```
$db = Db::connect();
$rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
foreach ($rows as $row ) {
   echo $row['someField'];
}
```